# whats wrong in below code, im trying to pass argument from di.xml to construction

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

```
namespace Ravi\Learn\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;
    public function __construct(Context $context, $customerSession)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getSess(){
       return $this->customerSession->getId();
    }
}
```

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Ravi\Learn\Helper\Data">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="customerSession" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Session</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your constructor look like this

```
public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
```

and you should not need the markup in `di.xml`

Comment: want to understand use of type in di.xml